# The error is Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: reactjs

I want to use this code to store the checkedbox  value in  workdays and this event is trigger when the check box is onchange
`enter code here`

```
const Post = (props) => {
  const [workdays, setForma] = React.useState([]);

  const  handlecheck = (event) => {
    let newArray = [...workdays, event.target.value];

    if (workdays.includes(event.target.value)) {
      newArray = newArray.filter(bhim => bhim !== event.target.value);
    }

    setForma({workdays:newArray});
  }
}
```

Comment: Other than the console log will only log the current state I don't see any overt issues with this snippet. Are you sure this is the code causing issue? Is there an error text/object and stacktrace you can update your question with?

Comment: app.js:148368 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
    at _nonIterableSpread (app.js:148368)

Comment: thanks in advance  why iam getting this error with that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with

```
setForma({workdays:newArray});
```

It seems you may have mixed up a class-based component's `this.setState` syntax with that of the functional component's `useState` react hook syntax.

`workdays` is an array, but this state update saves an object with key `workdays` and value of updated array. On the next change you try to spread an object into an array.

```
let newArray = [...workdays, event.target.value];
```

```js
foo = {a: 23, b: 42};
bar = [...foo, 'test']; // error!!
```

Simply update state with the new array value.

```
setForma(newArray);
```